# How to git clone with maven that uses an ssh-agent?

Tags: git, maven

I want to clone a repository with maven and the authentication must use an existing ssh-agent.

My current plugin configuration:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-scm-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.4</version>
    <configuration>
        <providerImplementations>
                <git>jgit</git>
        </providerImplementations>
    </configuration>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.scm</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-scm-provider-jgit</artifactId>
                <version>1.9.4</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>clone-github-wiki</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>checkout</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
            <configuration>
                <checkoutDirectory>${project.basedir}/target/github-wiki</checkoutDirectory>
                <connectionType>connection</connectionType>
                <connectionUrl>scm:git:git@github.com:xyz/abc.wiki.git</connectionUrl>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Authentication is failing:

```
[INFO] --- maven-scm-plugin:1.9.4:checkout (clone-github-wiki) @ xyz-doc ---
[INFO] Change the default 'git' provider implementation to 'jgit'.
[INFO] Removing /home/jenkins/abc/doc/target/github-wiki
[INFO] cloning [master] to /home/jenkins/abc/doc/target/github-wiki
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.490 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-10-14T11:45:40+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 15M/241M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-scm-plugin:1.9.4:checkout (clone-github-wiki) on project xyz-doc: Cannot run checkout command : Exception while executing SCM command. JGit checkout failure! git@github.com:abc/xyz.wiki.git: Auth fail -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exec plugin can be used to invoke the git command. In that case the ssh-agent is utilized.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.2</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>github-wiki-clone</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>exec</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
            <configuration>
                <executable>git</executable>
                <arguments>
                    <argument>clone</argument>
                    <argument>-b</argument>
                    <argument>master</argument>
                    <argument>git@github.com:abc/xyz.wiki.git</argument>
                    <argument>target/github-wiki</argument>
                </arguments>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Is there a possibility to skip this execution if the folder isnt empty?